# Connecting to MongoDb DB that is installed in different server

Tags: python, mongodb, ubuntu, digital-ocean

We have to servers. I have installed MongoDB on one of the servers (UBUNTU - Digital Ocean VPS).

When I run a script to retrieve data from the same server using a localhost, I can do that perfectly.

```
import pymongo
//SERVER = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myproject'
SERVER = 'mongodb://root:password@x.x.x.x:27017/myproject' where x.x.x.x is the address of my server 
connection=pymongo.MongoClient(SERVER)
db = connection.myproject
print list(db.coll.find())
```

The problem is thqt I can't connect to this DB. Note that I can ssh and run the script using localhost inside the server; but not the case out of the server.

Do I need to go through some configuration:

Answer (score 0):

You must allow remote access

> ```
> vi /etc/mongod.conf
> ```

## Listen only local interface.

bind_ip = 127.0.0.1

you must add the IP of your other servers. For Example:

## Listen local interface and 192.168.0.100.

bind_ip = 127.0.0.1, 192.168.0.100

Comment out to listen on all interfaces

Nota: Comma Separated

I hope to help

Comment: Thanks! What if I wanna use it from my PC

Comment: @user3378649 add the IP of your machine to bind_ip

Answer (score 0):

For development purposes you can open an ssh tunnel like

```
ssh <UBUNTU - Digital Ocean VPS> -L27018:localhost:27017
```

and then connect to the remote db as

```
SERVER = 'mongodb://root:password@localhost:27018/myproject'
```

while ssh connection remains open. You can use any free port instead of 27018.

Otherwise you need to reconfigure mongodb to listen to all interfaces. Comment out [`bindIp`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.bindIp) line in mongodb config and restart the server. This will make the DB publicly accessible, so make sure you use strong passwords and don't allow anonymous access.

Finally, if you are using VPN, you need to uncomment [`bindIp`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.bindIp) line in the mongodb config, and add VPN interface there, e.g.:

```
bindIp = 127.0.0.1,10.0.1.12
```

where 10.0.1.12 should be replaced with vpn interface of your ubuntu box. You can find exact value with `ifconfig`. Important: there are no spaces around coma.